# Regarding Getting An address for a text input field of an website

Tags: database, html, web, app-inventor

I am using a simple website called as `http://appinvtinywebdb.appspot.com/storeavalue`

Here basically one can store values in an variable online

there are two text input field in it 
one is tag , known as name of the variable
another one is value , known as value to be stored in the variable

I basically want to know the link i.e html adress where the value is stored example

```
 http://appinvtinywebdb.appspot.com/storeavalue/tag_123/value_66
```

something like this 
here 123 is name of variable and 66 is the value

Can any one of u help me find this link

I need it for my project where i need to send data from an gprs module on to a webdatabase..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store and get values with POST HTTP calls. I used a rest client to make de calls.

## Storing values

- Method: Post
- URL: http://appinvtinywebdb.appspot.com/storevalue
- Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Body or Payload: tag=yourTagName&value=yourValue

**yourTagName** and **yourValue** are the parameters to use.

## Getting values

- Method: Post
- URL: http://appinvtinywebdb.appspot.com/getvalue
- Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Body or Payload: tag=yourTagName&fmt=json

**yourTagName** is the name that you use in the **storevalue** method.

With **fmt=json** you get a json response.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: so to store value i need to type this as my url http://appinvtinywebdb.appspot.com/storevalue/application/x-www-form-urlencoded/tag=yourTagName&value=yourValue